# Inline VF Page with Link Not Working in Community

Tags: visualforce, community, inline-visualforce

I am using below Inline VF Page in Community but link is redirecting to VF Page instead of redirecting to the Contact Record:

[image: Inline VF Page]

[image: Community Inline VF Page]

[image: Link Redirection on Community]

Comment: Have you considered using [URLFOR](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_urlfor.htm&type=5)?